# Why gradle doesn't search for dependency in other maven repos?

Tags: maven, gradle, build-system, dependency-resolution

Why does gradle not searching for dependency in ALL defined maven repos?

Repos block is defined:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name = 'JBoss.org Maven repository'
        url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
    maven {
        name = 'spring-milestones'
        url 'http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

(Assuming I got somewhere in the subproject `net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.2.1`) I receive:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myproject:compileClasspath'.
> Could not find json-lib.jar (net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.2.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.2.1/json-lib-2.2.1.jar
```

Why the only one search-location? The `json-lib` clearly exists in `mavenCentral()`.

Is there any way to profile that, or debug somehow?

P.S. I could fix that if I move `mavenCentral()` up one position in the list of repos, but that will break another subproject dependency-resolution by the very same reason -- something from "spring" repo does not exist in `mavenCentral()`.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, gradle searches for all maven repos. You can see that JBoss repo does not contain 2.2.1 version of json-lib, so, it skips to the next one (spring repo).

Spring repo has 2.2.1, but, the issue here is that the artifact has distribution specified, so, you just need to fix the dependency:

```
compile 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.2.1:jdk15'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, everything was fine with the dependency, but still gradle was not able to locate the artifact from one of the 5 repositories I had.
What helped me was *--refresh-dependencies* option

i.e., `gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies`

I understand that I was not able to locate the exact problem, but this gave me a quick resolution. Note that all the dependencies will be downloaded again, which could take time

My gradle version is 6.5.1

Answer (score 0):

What works for me when this happens is going to my gradle cache in /Users/<username/.gradle/caches and searching for the dependency:

```
tree -f | grep exampleLib
│   │   │   ├── ./modules-2/files-2.1/com.example/exampleLib
│   │   │   │   ├── ./modules-2/files-2.1/com.example/exampleLib/0.0.1
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ./modules-2/files-2.1/com.example/exampleLib/0.0.1/1231161235123475345345235
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── ./modules-2/files-2.1/com.example
```

I use `tree` command but you can use `find` also. In this example my project is names `exampleLib` and has the the `com.example` group ID.

Then just delete the directory containing the dependency.

```
rm -f -R ./modules-2/files-2.1/com.example
```

Then click refresh in IntelliJ (if you use it), and do a `gradle clean build`.

[image]